# Check if an array of custom objects contains an object with a certain date

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsobject

I have an array of `event objects`. The object has several attributes. One of the attributes is an `NSDate eve_date`.

Now I want to check if that array of objects contains a certain `NSDate d`

I'm doing the following

```
if([[matches valueForKey:@"eve_date"] containsObject:d]){
        NSLog(@"contains object");
   }else{
    NSLog(@"does not contains object");
   }
```

But this is not working. Can anyone help me ?

Kind regards

**EDIT**

Okay let me be more clear. I'm making a calendar app. I fetched all the events inside the particular month. What I need to do now is to place a marker on my calendar on the correct date. Therefore I have this in a function.

```
NSLog(@"Delegate Range: %@ %@ %d",start,end,[start daysBetweenDate:end]);

    self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSDate *d = start;
    while(YES){
        for (Event *event in matches) {
            if([event.eve_date isEqualToDate:d]){
                //  (self.dataDictionary)[d] = save event title in here
                [self.dataArray addObject:@YES]; //place marker on date 'd'


            }else{
                [self.dataArray addObject:@NO]; // don't place marker
            }
        }


        NSDateComponents *info = [d dateComponentsWithTimeZone:calendar.timeZone];
        info.day++;
        d = [NSDate dateWithDateComponents:info];
        if([d compare:end]==NSOrderedDescending) break;
    }
```

But now I'm looping 31 times (amount of days off the month) through my array of events. (This is probably not the best practice solution ???)

I also think that the problem is that the time of the date is not the same. For example:

```
eve_date --> 2013-08-13 12:00
d --> 2013-08-13 15:00
```

So I probably should use an NSDateformatter to only get the date itself without the time ?

Am I correct ?

Comment: Have you checked (and logged) the contents of `[matches valueForKey:@"eve_date"]` ?

Comment: Does the solution have to use KVC?

Comment: You can do it through NSPredicate I guess.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Have you dumped `[matches valueForKey:@"eve_date"]` and checked if it contains a date that is equal to `d`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not very well versed with KVC, but if the solution doesn't need to use KVC, you can just iterate:

```
NSDate *dateToCompare = ...;
BOOL containsObject = NO;
for (MyEvent *e in matches)
{
    if ([e.eve_date isEqualToDate:dateToCompare]) 
    { 
        containsObject = YES;
        break;
    }
}

if (containsObject) NSLog(@"Contains Object");
else NSLog(@"Doesn't contain object");
```

---

I've had a play about with KVC and attempted a solution with that too. You were only missing `valueForKeyPath` instead of `valueForKey`

```
if ([[matches valueForKeyPath:@"eve_date"] containsObject:d])
{
    NSLog(@"Contains object");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Does not contain object");
}
```

Comment: Pretty simple and straightforward solution. +1

Comment: Finally got it working! Your answer helped me the most ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

`NSDate` is an absolute point in time. To check if a date falls on a given *day*,
you have to compare it with the "beginning of the day" and "beginning of the next day".

The following (pseudo-) code should demonstrate the idea:

```
NSDate *start, *end; // your given range

NSDate *currentDay = "beginning of" start;
// while currentDay < end:
while ([currentDay compare:end] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSDate *nextDay = currentDay "plus one day";
    for (Event *event in matches) {
        // if currentDay <= event.eve_date < nextDay:
        if ([event.eve_date compare:currentDay] != NSOrderedAscending
            && [event.eve_date compare:nextDay] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    currentDay = nextDay;
}
```

The "beginning of a day" can be computed as follows:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *aDate = ...;
NSDate *beginningOfDay;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&beginningOfDay interval:NULL forDate:aDate];
```