# NSFetchrequest with NSdate predicate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsfetchrequest

I have an `entity` which contains objects with an `NSDate (format yyyy-MM-dd)` Now I want to do a `fetch request` with only the objects that have an `NSDate` of today. So I'm doing the following.

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate new];
   RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[DominoDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"eve_date = %@",now];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"eve_date" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    arrConcerten = [matches mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"matches %@",matches);
```

My `NSLog` always returns no matches.

Can somebody help me with this?

**EDIT**

My entity contains NSDates like this:

```
2013/08/29
2013/08/30
2013/09/02
2013/09/15
2013/09/28
```

I thought that I just could compare these NSDates with the date of today? But this is maybe not working because the NSDates in my entity does not have an timestamp ?

Comment: There's no such thing as an `NSDate` with a "format". What, exactly, are the values in the `eve_date` attribute?

Comment: Isn't this (almost) the same problem as in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332769/check-if-an-array-of-custom-objects-contains-an-object-with-a-certain-date? - you have to compare with the "beginning of the day" and "beginning of the next day".

Comment: That doesn't look like an `NSDate` that's a formatted date string. When you look at the underlying persistent store what values do you find? Or, how are you populating these dates in code?

Answer (score 4):

your date is a timestamp that also contains seconds etc. What you need is a "between" predicate.

```
NSPredicate *subPredFrom = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eve_date >= %@ ", dateFrom];
[subpredicates addObject:subPredTo];

NSPredicate *subPredTo = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eve_date < %@", dateTo];
[subpredicates addObject:subPredFrom];
```

where dateTo is the next day 00:00 and dateFrom is the requested day 00:00 ;) to get this you have to use `NSDateComponents`

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSWeekCalendarUnit| [NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
[components setDay:components.day+1]; //
NSDate *tomorrow = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```